# Unable to install Cassandra package from Apache, repository is not signed error

Tags: cassandra

Snippet of cassandra installation progress:

```
RUN echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
RUN curl https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/KEYS | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update
```

Error output:

```
Failed to fetch http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian/dists/311x/InRelease  470  status code 470 
The repository 'http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x InRelease' is not signed.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note the part of [Downloading Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html) with "Installation from Debian packages". The repositories were moved to another URL.

Comment: Thank you. Found the latest debian package installation path `https://debian.cassandra.apache.org`